# Prevent screen down shift to the anchor at the responsive drop-down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

[menu screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3QNO.jpg)
When drop-down menu appears (id="sub-menu-1" or "sub-menu-2", etc) after the click on top buttons (class="toggle-1" or "toggle-2", etc), it shifts the display down to the anchor and hides the top button menu (class="mobile-menu"). How I can prevent this shift? I tryed "pointer-events: none;", but then drop-down menu doesn't work at all.

```
$('.mobile-menu').each(function() {
    var $_navbar  = $(this);
    var $_toggles = $_navbar.find('.toggle');
    var $_panels = $_navbar.find('.sub-menu');
    var active_classname = 'active';

$_toggles.each(function() {
    var $_this_toggle = $(this);
    var $_this_panel = $( $_this_toggle.attr('sm-id') );

    $_this_toggle.click(function() {                                    
        $_toggles.not($_this_toggle).removeClass(active_classname);
        $_this_toggle.toggleClass(active_classname);
        $_panels.not($_this_panel).slideUp();
        $_this_panel.stop().slideToggle();
    });
});
});

<nav class="mob-nav">
  <div class="mobile-menu">
     <a sm-id="#sub-menu-1" class="hotdog toggle toggle-1" href="#sub-menu-1"></a>
     <a sm-id="#sub-menu-2" class="mob-menu-mail toggle toggle-2" href="#sub-menu-2"></a>
     <a sm-id="#sub-menu-3" class="mob-menu-phone toggle toggle-3" href="#sub-menu-3"></a>
     <a sm-id="#sub-menu-4" class="mob-menu-search toggle toggle-4" href="#sub-menu-4"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="sub-menu-wrapper">
        <div id="sub-menu-1" class="sub-menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Продукция</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Технологии применения</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Объекты</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Документация</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">О компании</a></li>
            <li class="profile-links">
              <span>
                <a href="#">Заказчику</a>
              </span>
              <span>
                <a href="#">Проектировщику</a>
              </span>
            </li>
            <li class="profile-links">
              <span>
                <a href="#">Подрядчику</a>
              </span>
              <span>
                <a href="#">Частным клиентам</a>
              </span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="sub-menu-2" class="sub-menu">
          <form action="post" class="email-feedback">
            <input type="text" name="user-name" class="mob-nav-input" placeholder="Ваше имя">
            <input type="text" name="mobile-number" class="mob-nav-input" placeholder="Номер телефона">
            <textarea name="interest" class="mob-nav-input" placeholder="Что Вас интересует?"></textarea>
            <a href="#" class="button">Отправить</a>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div id="sub-menu-3" class="sub-menu">
          <ul>
            <li>+7 812 423-85-85</li>
            <li>+7 812 423-85-85</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="sub-menu-4" class="sub-menu">
          <form action="post" class="mobile-search">
            <input type="search" class="mob-nav-input">
            <input type="submit" class="search-param-sub" value="">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
```

```
.mobile-menu {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.mobile-menu a {
    border: #3a3a3a 1px solid;
    height: 60px;
    display: block;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}

.sub-menu {
    padding-top: 10px;
    display: none;
}
```

Where I should search the solution? In CSS or JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

```
$_this_toggle.click(function(e) {                                    
  e.preventDefault();
```

Since your anchors have an `href` which begins with a `#` and that hash value corresponds to an element on the page with the same `id` or `name` browsers will scroll the page down to the matching element, and also change the hash in the URL. You need to prevent the default browser behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

add to a tag this `onclick="event.preventDefault()"`

```
<a onclick="event.preventDefault()" sm-id="#sub-menu-2" class="mob-menu-mail toggle toggle-2" href="#sub-menu-2"></a>
```

the simplest solution is this. when you click a tag with attribute href="#example" naturally it is forcing browser to go a tag which has id="example" attribute. Avoid for this you should use event.preventDefault() properly